# How to can i display a value of a selected button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The following code creates a Buttons, with CSS when one of the button is clicked it changes color, each button created has its own value.
So i want to display a VALUE of a selected button if clicked on my HTML page how can manage that?

```
function createButtons(tbID, tbClass, tbType, tbValue, onClick) {
    return '\n<input '
            + (tbID ? ' id=\'' + tbID + '\'' : '')
            + (tbClass ? ' class=\'' + tbClass + '\'' : '')
            + (tbType ? ' type=\'' + tbType + '\'' : '')
            + (tbValue ? ' value=\'' + tbValue + '\'' : '')
            + (onClick ? ' onclick=\'toggle(this);' + onClick + '\'' : '')
            + '>';
}

function toggle(ths) {
  $(ths).toggleClass("btnColor");
   $("#tb").toggleClass("btnColorR");  
}

function DisplayButtons(cableData) {
  var newContent = '';
  $.each(cableData,
    function (i, item) {
      newContent += createButtons("tb" + item.CommonCable, null, "submit",       item.CommonCable,toggle);
  });
  $("#Categories").html(newContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(ths).val()` or `$(ths).attr('val')` will get you the value.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nbeZ2/)